# IOS Tutorial Exception (ToDo Sample)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed this [IOS Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1) using XCode 5.0.2 and have come to a road block :(

I have implemented the portion in Adding items to the ToDo list and this is where the problem begins.

This is in my AddToDoItemViewController which happens when I select done:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if(sender != self.doneButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(self.textField.text.length > 0)
    {
        self.todoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.todoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.todoItem.completed = NO;
    }
```

}

Once that is done, I receive a call to the following method which is suppose to add the Item to the Mutable Array in my ToDoListViewController:

```
- (IBAction) unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    AddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    ToDoItem *item = source.todoItem;
    if(item != nil)
    {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

What I noticed is if I do not type anything in the Text Field and just click add from List then hit cancel or done, there are no exceptions and the views switch from Add To Do Item back to List View. BUT if I type anything in the textField and select either cancel or done, and exception is thrown.

```
2014-01-26 22:28:15.301 ToDoList[2537:a0b] -[AddToDoItemViewController textField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89c4b60
2014-01-26 22:28:15.310 ToDoList[2537:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AddToDoItemViewController textField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89c4b60'
```

Some guidance would be appreciated so I can get this working. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After many hours of looking and trying to understand why the exception happened, I have finally found why.

I went to storyboard and right clicked on text field. I found that one of the Send Events was linked to a method (Editing Did End to be specific). No idea how this link was made, but I deleted the link. The only link that I saw was under Referencing Outlets which was pointing to the textField in AddToDoItemViewController.m. Once I tried it again, IT WORKED. Thanks to all who gave suggestions.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint so you can find the exact line that is crashing. Somewhere, you are calling a method on an AddToDoItemViewController called `textField:(something)something` and this method does not exist.

Comment: Can you check do you have `@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;` in your AddToDoItemViewController ?

Comment: I have this in the @interface block: 
<pre>#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
 
interface AddToDoItemViewController ()
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
 
end</pre>

Please advise if there is something else I should check.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary: It is a problem linking your UIObject with your Controller.**

Maybe I'm late, but this would be helpful for anyone else because it took to me up to 2 hours realising for being a beginner here.

I dragged the textField (input) to the controller in order to create a reference.

I made a mistake because I dragged the reference to the implementation zone instead of doing to the internal interface.

When I realised of that, I deleted the code generated in my controller, **but I didn't delete the reference from the object!!!**

To completely delete the reference, you should pick the object with your secondary mouse button and remove the useless reference (outlets) to your controller.

Answer (score -1):

you have forgot to connect the textfield in xib

[Please follow up the below specified section in this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html)

**To connect the text field to your view controller**

Comment: I thought I did. I have this in the AddToDoItemViewController.m

    <code>@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    </code>

Comment: yes you may have, but make sure it was connected in IB's textfield

Comment: Sorry but Im not sure I understand. Here is what I did:
1. I went to storeboard and click on textField
2. I then opened Assistant editor and had AddToDoItemViewController.m open along side StoryBoard
3. I ctrl + dragged right below @interface of AddToDoItemViewController
4. Then I added Connect via Outlet and gave name textField then clicked connect.

Is there another step Im missing?

Comment: I am ready to accept the downvote, but please specify the reason for that. so that i can avoid it next time. thanks