# Firguring out reasons for exceptions in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

After I completed the tutorial: [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/iOSTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH11-SW1)

I got the same exception asked here: [IOS Tutorial Exception (ToDo Sample)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374625/ios-tutorial-exception-todo-sample)
and the app crashed but it would not crash if I started a debugging session and stepped through the code.

```
2015-05-04 16:09:51.569 ToDoList[9223:67681] -[AddToDoItemViewController textField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe570d4eff0
2015-05-04 16:09:51.574 ToDoList[9223:67681] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AddToDoItemViewController textField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe570d4eff0'
```

Then I solved the mystery by reading out this post: [IOS Tutorial Exception (ToDo Sample)](http://www.4byte.cn/question/143639/ios-tutorial-exception-todo-sample.html)

The reason was that I wrongly connected the text field to the @implemenation section instead of to the @interface section and it created some method that I deleted. Of course I forgot about that soon after that.

How could I have figured out myself without knowing anything of the above what was the reason to get that exception and where it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log message is telling you that something was trying to call `-textField:` method of your `AddToDoItemViewController`.

So the first step would be to check if that method is implemented - in your case it was not. You might have been confused by the presence of

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* textField
```

but auto synthesis for property generates getter with the signature `-textField`, which is different from `-textField:` (latter takes one parameter, while former none).

Comment: So you mean that this: -[AddToDoItemViewController textField:]: is telling me that I am calling a non-existing method and that is not caught by the compiler at compile time? Nice!

Comment: Due to dynamic nature of Objective-C, it is not always possible to catch this sort of thing at compile time - it is in fact allowed to call any method on any object, although most of the time compiler raises warning / error.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that you're trying to access the `textView` property of `AddToDoItemViewController`, but it doesn't have one.

So your next step would've been to go and check that you have a property like that declared and being an outlet that it's properly connected in the Interface Builder.

**Edit:**
Sorry I wasn't paying enough attention.
The selector that it's trying to call is `textField:` so it must be a function starting like that. I assume you set the controller as a TextView delegate but didn't implement the required method.

Comment: Yes there was one: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField; That was the confusing part.